# Creating List from NameValueCollection

Tags: c#

I have `NameValueCollection` type:

```
NameValueCollection args = new NameValueCollection();
```

I also create a list of NameValueCollection:

```
List<NameValueCollection> argsList = new List<NameValueCollection>();
```

Then I feel args variable and add to argsList:

```
foreach (var point in points)
{
    args = new NameValueCollection();

    args.Add("SESSION", ViewState[MgConstants.STR_SESSION].ToString());
    args.Add("MAPNAME", ViewState[MgConstants.STR_MAPNAME].ToString());
    args.Add("DIR", "");
    args.Add("TEXT", point.text);

    argsCollection.Concat(args);
}
```

My question is it a good practice to create List from NameValueCollection?

**UPDATE**

My goal is to iterate through List using loop.For this purpose I make List of NameValueCollection. Do I must to create a List to itarate or there any another way to achive it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for here. Sure, you can create a `List<NameValueCollection>` - but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so we can't tell whether or not it's a useful thing to do. (Calling `Concat` is almost certainly not what you want though... `Add` perhaps? Not that you've shown what `argsCollection` is... your list is `argsList`.)

Comment: a collection and a list, in some ways, are the same things. If you ask "is it a good practice to create List from NameValueCollection?", I would say no, because you are creating a "list of a list", which do not have a purpose in your question. Please edit you question and make i more clear.

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus please see update

Comment: Maybe you could use LINQ?

Comment: Can you please provide example?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking whether you need to loop, but that depends really on what you need to do. Going by your updated statement, you want to transform your `points` which is an `IEnumerable` into a `List<NameValueCollection>`

To do so, you can use LINQ and don't need to iterate, as such:

```
argsCollection = points.Select(a => new NameValueCollection()
{
    { "SESSION", ViewState[MgConstants.STR_SESSION].ToString() },
    { "MAPNAME", ViewState[MgConstants.STR_MAPNAME].ToString() },
    { "DIR", "" },
    { "TEXT", a.text }
});
```

this assumes that `argsCollection` is an `IEnumerable`. If it is a `List<T>`, add `.ToList()` after the `.Select()` statement.